# package 'rms' - singular information matrix encountered

Tags: r, logistic, splines, regression-strategies

I am trying to fit a binary logistic regression model using only one predictor. After consulting a loess plot I decided to use *restricted cubic spline* to fit the curve (with default 4 knots). Using  'rms' package:

```
lrm(y ~ rcs(x), data = data)
```

however I encounter the following problem:

```
singular information matrix in lrm.fit (rank= 3 ).  Offending variable(s):
x''' x'' 
Error in lrm(y ~ rcs(x), data = data) : 
  Unable to fit model using “lrm.fit”
```

Why am I getting this issue? and how do I solve it?
[image]

(N=61829), Min=-29000, 1st Qu.=0 , Median.=300 ,  Mean=7260 ,  3rd Qu.=6190 ,   Max.=240000

Comment: Show us a high-resolution histogram of the distribution of x (e.g., 100 or 200 bins).

Comment: It's the clumping at zero that creates the problem: hard to figure out which knots to use.  Override default knots with constants you select, or use a regular polynomial, e.g. `pol(x, 2)`.  Or with your extreme skewness, `pol(sqrt(x), 2)`.  Also use `sqrt(x)` inside `rcs`, or cube root.

Comment: do you need the loes plot also? @FrankHarrell

Comment: The relationship is exactly what I expect: maxium at about 0(a bit less than 0) , a rise at 10000 then decay .

Comment: any suggestions where to put the knots.

Comment: What does the 2nd graph represent and how do you know to have faith in it?

Comment: Try putting knots at 1.0 and these quantiles of the nonzero values of x: 0.05 0.275 0.5 0.725 0.95